# Разделить диапазон дат на месяца (начало-конец)

Tags: datetime, php7, diff

Есть диапазон дат, например:

```
$interval_start = '2018-05-20';
$interval_end = '2018-07-15';
```

Задача: разделить этот диапазон на месяца, найти начало и конец месяца. Т.е. должно получиться примерно так:

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2018-05-20
            [1] => 2018-05-21
            [2] => 2018-05-22
            [3] => 2018-05-23
            [4] => 2018-05-24
            [5] => 2018-05-25
            [6] => 2018-05-26
            [7] => 2018-05-27
            [8] => 2018-05-28
            [9] => 2018-05-29
            [10] => 2018-05-30
            [11] => 2018-05-31
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2018-06-01
            [1] => 2018-06-02
            [2] => 2018-06-03
            [3] => 2018-06-04
            [4] => 2018-06-05
            [5] => 2018-06-06
            [6] => 2018-06-07
            [7] => 2018-06-08
            [8] => 2018-06-09
            [9] => 2018-06-10
            [10] => 2018-06-11
            [11] => 2018-06-12
            [12] => 2018-06-13
            [13] => 2018-06-14
            [14] => 2018-06-15
            [15] => 2018-06-16
            [16] => 2018-06-17
            [17] => 2018-06-18
            [18] => 2018-06-19
            [19] => 2018-06-20
            [20] => 2018-06-21
            [21] => 2018-06-22
            [22] => 2018-06-23
            [23] => 2018-06-24
            [24] => 2018-06-25
            [25] => 2018-06-26
            [26] => 2018-06-27
            [27] => 2018-06-28
            [28] => 2018-06-29
            [29] => 2018-06-30
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2018-07-01
            [1] => 2018-07-02
            [2] => 2018-07-03
            [3] => 2018-07-04
            [4] => 2018-07-05
            [5] => 2018-07-06
            [6] => 2018-07-07
            [7] => 2018-07-08
            [8] => 2018-07-09
            [9] => 2018-07-10
            [10] => 2018-07-11
            [11] => 2018-07-12
            [12] => 2018-07-13
            [13] => 2018-07-14
            [14] => 2018-07-15
       )
)
```

Пробовал использовать DateInterval (верно отрабатывает, если делить на недели), но по месяцам делит не корректно:

```
$interval = new DateInterval('P1D');
    $dateRange = new DatePeriod($start, $interval, $end);

    $weekNumber = 1;
    $weeks = array();
    foreach ($dateRange as $date) {
        $weeks[$weekNumber][] = $date->format('Y-m-d');
        if ($date->format('j') == 1) {
            $weekNumber++;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$period = new DatePeriod(
   new DateTime('2018-05-20'),
   new DateInterval('P1D'),
   (new DateTime('2018-07-15'))->modify('+1 day')
);

$months = array();
foreach ($period as $date) {
   $months[(int)$date->format('m') - 5][] = $date->format('Y-m-d');
}
var_dump($months);
```